# Consolidating CSVs in a directory using merge() and lapply(), errors

Tags: r, csv, merge, directory, lapply

So I want to consolidate every csv in a given directory into one data frame. A google search shows many possible answers, but most of them require creating a unique function, while also creating column names manually, which I would rather not do.

The solution that most interested me is this one:

```
file_names <- dir('/Users/directory') 
history <- do.call(merge,lapply(file_names,read.csv))
```

This worked last night and I was quite happy, but this morning it did not work. I think I know the reason why. It seems to work *only when I have two csv's*. Just now, I deleted one of my csv's, and now it works.

Just for reference, every csv in my directory follows this format:

```
x |v(date)
```

That is, I will have a csv file named "data.04.15.2017", where the column 1 is named `x` and column 2 is named `v.04.15.2017` (note that the column is the date of the day it was created, which is reflected in the name as well).

When I try to run the first script from above, I get an error saying:

`Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
  'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical`

Is it the case that having the same name for the first column in all three csv files creates this error? As far as I know, every row is the exact same in all three, and they match line by line as well. Just to reiterate, this seems to work fine when I only have two csv files, but this morning when I had three I had the above error. If having the same name for the first column is a problem, would this mean that I would have to use a different function other than `merge()`? I can do `cbind()` but that would require creating an addition number vector, just so that I could delete repeating columns, which I would rather avoid.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: could you try replacing merge with rbind?

Comment: I am not sure rbind is what I am looking for. I want a time series master csv file; therefore I want ultimate data frame to follow the format (the following are columns): `x | v.04.15.2017|v.04.16.2017|v.04.17.2017 ... `, and so on. I think rbind would add the dataframe "below" the first one, if that makes sense. I want my data frames to be appended next to each other.

Comment: Setting aside my minor confusion about your csv's apparently being pipe-delimited (?), personally I'd adjust each data frame as they come in so that the date is repeated in a new, third column called `date` and then rename the data column `val` or something. Then just `rbind` them. If you really need it in wide format, convert it via `reshape` or `tidyr::spread` or something.

Comment: @joran I am not sure what a pipe-delimeted is. I have one script that takes a table from a website and uploads it as a csv (with the date in the name) into a specific directory. Then I have a separate script (the one we are discussing here) where I essentially take all the csv files and combine them into one big data frame. Is there not a way of combining all these csv files in the directory all at once, when I so choose? I would hate to have to be obligated to update the large data frame day by day.

Comment: (1) csv typically refers to comma-separated values e.g. `val1,val2,val3`. What you've written in your question is `val1 | val2 | val3`, but that's probably beside the point, it's just confusing for those of us reading. (2) I'm not sure how what I described isn't a way to combine the files all at once; it's just easier to do if you put them in a sensible format first.

Comment: @joran ohh I see. I am sorry. I used the "|" to denote the different columns. This in no way refers to the data format, it is indeed csv. And I think . I get what you mean. My `X` column, though, is a list of names. So if if `rbind` two datasets, the names will be repeated. I was just hoping that there was a way to combine all the files neatly in one step, without having to resort to restructuring it via `respape`.